# Batch file 'choice' command's errorlevel returns 0

Tags: file, batch-file, command, errorlevel, batch-choice

I'm trying to create a batch file that performs different 'choice' command based on the version of Windows being executed on. The choice command's syntax is different between Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Choice command returns a 1 for Y and 2 for N. The following command returns the correct error level:

Windows 7:

```
choice /t 5 /d Y /m "Do you want to automatically shutdown the computer afterwards "
echo %errorlevel%
if '%errorlevel%'=='1' set Shutdown=T
if '%errorlevel%'=='2' set Shutdown=F
```

Windows XP:

```
choice /t:Y,5 "Do you want to automatically shutdown the computer afterwards "
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='1' set Shutdown=T
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='2' set Shutdown=F
```

However, when it is combined with a command to detect the Windows OS version, errorlevel returns 0 before AN after the choice command in both my Windows XP and Windows 7 blocks of code.

```
REM Windows XP
ver | findstr /i "5\.1\." > nul
if '%errorlevel%'=='0' (
set errorlevel=''
echo %errorlevel%
choice /t:Y,5 "Do you want to automatically shutdown the computer afterwards "
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='1' set Shutdown=T
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='2' set Shutdown=F
echo.
)

REM Windows 7
ver | findstr /i "6\.1\." > nul
if '%errorlevel%'=='0' (
set errorlevel=''
echo %errorlevel%
choice /t 5 /d Y /m "Do you want to automatically shutdown the computer afterwards "
echo %errorlevel%
if '%errorlevel%'=='1' set Shutdown=T
if '%errorlevel%'=='2' set Shutdown=F
echo.
)
```

As you can see, I even tried clearing the errorlevel var before executing the choice command, but errorlevel remains at 0 after the choice command is executed.

Any tips?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

You have run across a classic problem - You are attempting to expand `%errorlevel%` within a parenthesized block of code. That form of expansion occurs at parse time, but the entire IF construct is parsed at once, so the value of `%errorlevel%` will not change.

The solution is simple - delayed expansion. You need `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top, and then use `!errorlevel!` instead. Delayed expansion occurs at execution time, so then you are able to see the changes to the value within the parentheses.

The help for SET (`SET /?`) describes the problem and the solution with regards to a FOR statement, but the concept is the same.

You have other options.

You can move the code from within the body of the `IF` to labeled sections of code without parentheses, and use `GOTO` or `CALL` to access the code. Then you can use `%errorlevel%`. I don't like this option because `CALL` and `GOTO` are relatively slow, and the code is less elegant.

Another option is to use `IF ERRORLEVEL N` instead of `IF !ERRORLEVEL!==N`. (See `IF /?`) Because `IF ERRORLEVEL N` tests if errorlevel is >= N, you need to perform your tests in descending order.

```
REM Windows XP
ver | findstr /i "5\.1\." > nul
if '%errorlevel%'=='0' (
  choice /t:Y,5 "Do you want to automatically shutdown the computer afterwards "
  if ERRORLEVEL 2 set Shutdown=F
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 set Shutdown=T
)
```