# batch choice command not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Okay I am trying to ask the user the below question in a batch file but don't think that I am entering the correct choice command.

```
    echo Would you like to know the time? (Y/N)
    CHOICE /C YN /N
    GOTO OPTION-%ERRORLEVEL%

    :OPTION-Y  Yes 
    echo %time%
    goto cont

    :OPTION-N  No

    :cont
```

P.S today is my first day of the couse so I am a newbie, please don't judge.

Comment: So you didn't bother to read the help for the `CHOICE` command. **The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.**

Answer (score 2):

Because `%errorlevel%` is a number not `Y` or `N`

Your labels should be `:OPTION-1` and `:OPTION-2`:

```
@echo off
echo Would you like to know the time? (Y/N)
CHOICE /C YN /N
GOTO OPTION-%ERRORLEVEL%

:OPTION-1
echo %time%
goto cont

:OPTION-2

:cont
```

Here is another example so you can understand how it assigns the `%errorlevel%` number to the key you selected.

```
@echo off
:start
cls
CHOICE /C YNM /N /M "Should I display the Time? Select (Yes (Y)  No (N) or Maybe (M))"
if %errorlevel%==1 echo %time%
if %errorlevel%==2 echo Ok, I won't then
if %errorlevel%==3 echo it is fine, I will ask again in 10 seconds & timeout /T 10 & goto :start
```

Here you can see it assigns the first key to `%errorlevel% 1`, the second key to `%errorlevel% 2` and third key to `%errorlevel% 3` etc.

Comment: So if I press Y on the keyboard, it will trigger option1?

Comment: @Snoopy135 Correct Yes. I tested already. just copy the code as is

Comment: @Gerhard, in your second example, `%DRIVE%` will always be assigned the value `A:`, you need to either reverse the `ERRORLEVEL`s from `5` to `1` or change the `IF` sequences to use `%ERRORLEVEL%` and `==`.

Comment: @compo, I did not actually see that as I got the example from robvanderwoude, but yes, I will fix it.

Comment: This will not work in a parenthesized block -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616822/733092.

Comment: @noumenon, yes we know, but we do not need delayedexpansion here,  so not really relevant here?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I upvoted because this is a good answer to OP's question. I commented to help people who tried this answer and it inexplicably didn't work, like me.

Comment: @noumenon, Thanks for the upvote. I did not critisize in my comment. It was a reponse with a question.:)

Answer (score 0):

`CHOICE` does not return the selected key as `%ERRORLEVEL%`, it returns the *index* of the selected key - that is, for `CHOICE /C YN`, if you select ***Y***, `%ERRORLEVEL%` will be 1; for ***N***, it will be 2. See [SS64 on `CHOICE`](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html).

You also have to be careful about the order that you test `%ERRORLEVEL%`; the standard construct `IF ERRORLEVEL n ...` is actually testing to see whether `%ERRORLEVEL%` is ***equal to or greater than*** n. See [SS64 on `ERRORLEVEL`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could also reduce all of your provided snippet to two lines, *(continuing your script beneath them as necessary)*:

```bat
Choice /M "Would you like to know the time"
If Not ErrorLevel 2 Echo %TIME% & Timeout 3 >Nul
```

Comment: I think judging by his question, OP is doing an assignment and they probably have to use labels, but I could be wrong.